# Is one allowed to eat foods that were grown from non-kosher materials?

Tags: halacha, minhag, kashrut-kosher

There is a known story of how one time a person brought a giant carrot on Erev Pesach to the Belzer Rebbe (back in Europe) for Karpas. After the donor left, he said "burn it with the Chometz". As the donor came home, his non-Jewish maid told him that she saw that he wanted this carrot to be a special carrot for his Rebbe. To help, she decided to water it with beer.

The farmer ran back and told the Rebbe what happened. The Chassidim were amazed at this miraculous occurrence, but the Rebbe answered "It was no miracle. It's just that we don't use carrots for karpas".

---

I have two questions:

1. Is there a *halacha* prohibiting one from eating a food on pesach whose entire growth was from Chometz? (Or was it a Chumra?)
2. Does this rule apply throughout the year (is one permitted to eat a carrot that grew on blood, for example)?

Comment: do you have a source for the story?

Comment: on pesach chametz is compared to avoda zara and like in the case of idol worship there is no limit to what someone may prohibit themselves to avoid the say is true of chametz on pesach. Therefore even when a chumra may not appear to be entirely logical it is the one area of kashrus where it is not only permissible but positive to have extreme chumras. (said in the name of the arizal by local orthodox rabbi explaining how some chumras on pesach are allowed that don't make sense)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rav Moshe Feinstein discusses the milk of an animal which ate chametz.

> From **שו"ת אגרות משה אורח חיים חלק א סימן קמז**
>
> ונמצא לפי חדוש זה שחלב של בהמת נכרי שאכלה חמץ אין להחמיר אף לבעלי נפש
> כיון שאף להרמ"א אין מקום לאסור.   זהו הנלע"ד בסוגיא זו להלכה וגם למעשה
> הכותב בימי עניו ומרודו ומצפה לישועת ה' גיסו כאחיו אוהבו, משה פיינשטיין

He concludes that one may drink milk that comes from an animal that ate chametz. He says there is no reason to be machmir whatsoever.

I recommend you take a look at the full teshuva. He discusses the Rama who discusses the machloket of a chicken that ate nothing but issurim.

> **דרכי משה הקצר יורה דעה סימן ס**
>
> במרדכי ביבמות פרק אלמנה לכהן גדול (סי'
> סו) בהמה או תרנגולת שנתפטמה בדבר האסור או שרצים שריא אבל בתוספות
> דתמורה פרק כל האסורים (לא. ד"ה שינקה) כתבו דאם לא נתפטמה כל ימיה רק
> באיסור אסורה ועיין לקמן סימן פ"א (אות ז):‏